# Hide certain categorical element from legend in Plotnine

Tags: python, plotnine

In Plotnine, is it possible to hide certain legend elements?

```py
mpg_select = mpg[mpg["manufacturer"].isin(pd.Series(["audi", "ford", "honda", "hyundai"]))]
```

I have selected only 4 manufacturers. But when I plot the data, I still see the manufacturers that are not in the data as elements for my legend.

```py
(ggplot(mpg_select, aes(x="displ", y="cty"))
    + geom_jitter(aes(size="hwy", color="manufacturer"))
    + geom_smooth(aes(color="manufacturer"), method="lm", se=False)
    + labs(title="Bubble chart")
)
```

[image: Plotnine result showing complete legends for manufacturer]

How do I show only the manufacturer that I selected (audi, ford, honda, and hyundai) as my legend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `manufacturer` column is categorical and it still has all those categories. You can remove the categories from the column and the extra values will remove from the legend.

```
from plotnine.data import mpg

desired_manufacturers = ['audi','ford','honda','hyundai']
mpg_select = mpg.loc[mpg['manufacturer'].isin(desired_manufacturers)]
mpg_select['manufacturer_subset'] = pd.Categorical(mpg_select['manufacturer'],
                                                   categories=desired_manufacturers)

(ggplot(mpg_select, aes(x="displ", y="cty"))
    + geom_jitter(aes(size="hwy", color="manufacturer_subset"))
    + geom_smooth(aes(color="manufacturer_subset"), method="lm", se=False)
    + labs(title="Bubble chart")
)
```

[image: plot_with_manufacturer_subset]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I found that `remove_unused_categories()` did a cleaner job. You don't need to create a new variable, it just removes the missing categories after the filtering:

```
    from plotnine.data import mpg

    desired_manufacturers = ['audi','ford','honda','hyundai']
    mpg_select = mpg.loc[mpg['manufacturer'].isin(desired_manufacturers)]
    
    mpg_select["manufacturer"] = mpg_select["manufacturer"].cat.remove_unused_categories()

    (ggplot(mpg_select, aes(x="displ", y="cty"))
        + geom_jitter(aes(size="hwy", color="manufacturer"))
        + geom_smooth(aes(color="manufacturer"), method="lm", se=False)
        + labs(title="Bubble chart")
    )
```

[image]